# Video conversion stops while converting .avi movie to 3GP using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

```
..\tools\ffmpeg -y -i FindingNemo(2003)WidescreenDVDripV3nDetta.avi -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k  -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 24k FindingNemo(2003)WidescreenDVDripV3nDetta.3gp
```

I'm using the above script for converting a movie to 3GB. The conversion is successful if the duration of the video is short. But when it's a movie, ffmpeg stops conversion after certain number of frames.

```
C:\Users\Priya\Desktop\PicvieBuilder_Essilor_Version1\builder_latest\WPF_Explore
r_Tree\bin\Debug>.\tools\ffmpeg -y -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k -i "E:\priya\Movies\
Finding Nemo (2003) Widescreen DVDrip V3nDetta\FindingNemo(2003)WidescreenDVDrip
V3nDetta.avi" -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 24k "E:\priya\
Movies\Finding Nemo (2003) Widescreen DVDrip V3nDetta\FindingNemo(2003)Widescree
nDVDripV3nDetta.3gp"
FFmpeg version SVN-r23607, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 15 2010 04:09:35 with gcc 4.4.2
  configuration: --target-os=mingw32 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynt
h --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libfaad
 --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --ena
ble-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libxvid --enable-libschroedinger --
enable-libx264 --extra-libs='-lx264 -lpthread' --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enab
le-libopencore_amrnb --enable-librtmp --extra-libs='-lrtmp -lpolarssl -lws2_32 -
lwinmm' --arch=x86 --cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc='ccache i686-mingw32-gcc' -
-enable-memalign-hack
  libavutil     50.19. 0 / 50.19. 0
  libavcodec    52.76. 0 / 52.76. 0
  libavformat   52.68. 0 / 52.68. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.20. 0 /  1.20. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
[avi @ 016a7270]max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, avi, from 'E:\priya\Movies\Finding Nemo (2003) Widescreen DVDrip V3nDe
tta\FindingNemo(2003)WidescreenDVDripV3nDetta.avi':
  Metadata:
    INAM            : FINDING_NEMO.Title1.DVDRip
    IPRD            : FINDING_NEMO
    ISFT            : Lavf52.78.4
  Duration: 01:40:31.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1363 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x360, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn,
 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 448 kb/s
Output #0, 3gp, to 'E:\priya\Movies\Finding Nemo (2003) Widescreen DVDrip V3nDet
ta\FindingNemo(2003)WidescreenDVDripV3nDetta.3gp':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.68.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: h263, yuv420p, 640x360, q=2-31, 400 kb/s, 24k tbn, 23.98
 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 24 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame= 2509 fps=250 q=17.2 size=    5632kB time=104.45 bitrate= 441.7kbits/s
frame= 2620 fps=249 q=15.9 size=    5844kB time=109.06 bitrate= 439.0kbits/s
frame= 2727 fps=247 q=10.3 size=    6058kB time=113.54 bitrate= 437.1kbits/s
```

Comment: For the future: Paste the code, then select it and press the `{}` button or `Ctrl-K` to format it as code. As for your question: You're using a terribly outdated version of ffmpeg. It's now almost 4 years old. Can you please download a newer one and try again? http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: yeah sure..Let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r23607, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
```

This is clearly outdated. Thousands of bugs have been fixed in the meantime. You can download a newer version of ffmpeg here and try again:

http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: There is one more problem.My pc is a 64 bit pc.I have downloaded ffmpeg-20130801-git-f118b41-win64-static version of ffmpeg from the site http://ffmpeg.org/download.html .It is working fine in all 64 bit pcs.But if it is a 32 bit machine ,video conversion is not hapening.I want this to work on both type of pc's.What shall i do?

Comment: Just download the 32-bit version. It will also run on 64-bit machines.

Comment: Its working with the 32 bit version.Thanks